# argparse input range function

Tags: python, function, argparse

I need to pass a function in command line and parsing with argparse.
How can I do that?

Eg.
`python program.py --params a=range(1, 10, 1), b=range(2, 5, 1)...`

I've tested:
`parser.add_argument('-p', "--params", type=json.loads)`

But when I try to launch cmd:
`python program.py --p {"a": range(1, 10, 1}`

returns this error:
`error: argument -p/--params: invalid loads value: '{"a": range(1,10,1)}'`

Comment: When trying to supply commandline values with spaces and special characters, it's a good idea to verify what the shell has done with them.  `import sys` and `print(sys.argv)` will give you an idea of what the parser has to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create your own custom function for that and pass it in `type`

e.g.

```
>>> def hyphenated(string):
...     return '-'.join([word[:4] for word in string.casefold().split()])
...
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> _ = parser.add_argument('short_title', type=hyphenated)
>>> parser.parse_args(['"The Tale of Two Cities"'])
Namespace(short_title='"the-tale-of-two-citi')
```

more info: [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type)